# APNS issues with windows server Push Notification iOS

Tags: php, ios, windows, certificate, apple-push-notifications

I'm having issues when uploading and running my php script to a windows web server.

The php (with accompanying certificate and key) works on my local machine, but not when I upload and run the script from the web server.

Is this a certificate issue? I've followed many different tutorials, but am obviously missing some fundamental piece.

The tutorial I used to get the push working on my Mac's local MAMP server is: http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

I've also found the following thread which seems to have solved the issue, but I can seem to get it working myself :( ... "This took me forever to figure out but I finally pieced it all together from the minor clues people left." [http://arashnorouzi.wordpress.com/2011/06/19/sending-apple-push-notifications-in-asp-net-and-c-–-part-4-apns-sharp-c-wrapper-class/](http://arashnorouzi.wordpress.com/2011/06/19/sending-apple-push-notifications-in-asp-net-and-c-%E2%80%93-part-4-apns-sharp-c-wrapper-class/)

Comment: no ... the in-house server never worked. I uploaded the necessary file to my own personal godaddy server and it did work. Thus, there must be some wrong server settings or a firewall issue :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the certificate for the APPID that you register on the developer portal. That certificate must be converted into a P12 format to be used on Windows.

If you are running Yosemite, the easiest way to do this is to import the certificate to your keychain, then export it to a .p12 file.